# Logging into an RDP/S session

Tags: remote-desktop

**UPDATE 1:**

I've now tried the following which gives me an error.

```
oshirowanen@desktop:~$ sudo xfreerdp /v:farm.company.com /d:company.com /u:username /g:gateway.company.com
transport_connect: getaddrinfo (Name or service not known)
Error: protocol security negotiation failure
oshirowanen@desktop:~$
```

Anyone know why I get this error?

---

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**

From a windows machine, I can log into an rdp session simply by starting mstsc, entering in the gateway details and then entering in the computer details

```
gateway = gateway.company.com
computer = farm.company.com
user = domain\username
```

Can I do this with Linux?  I have downloaded and installed Gnome's Remote Desktop Viewer application, and I can't see a gateway option.  I can only see a host option and a user option.

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78653/rdp-only-operating-system

Comment: Are you trying to RDP to a windows machine from a Linux box?

Comment: @slm, that's right.  My question doesn't make that clear does it?

Comment: @slm, I am basically after rdp client software which has a terminal services gateway option when connecting to an rdp windows session I guess.

Comment: OK, then see my updates, I completely misunderstood what you were asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### 1. Windows RDP client ⇢ Linux RDP server

From your question it isn't clear whether you're attempting to RDP into a Linux system or a Windows system. If it's a Linux system you're ultimately trying to RDP into then you'll need special software to enable RDP clients to connect to a Linux system via RDP.

There is a project called XRDP that you can install on a Linux system which allows for any RDP clients to connect to the box. The setup of this software can be a little tricky but it works well.

XRDP is basically a frontend that wraps VNC, so you're talking to the Linux system like so:

```
(Windows Desktop) ---> MSTSC ---> XRDP ---> VNC ---> (Linux Desktop)
```

- http://www.xrdp.org/

#### 2. Linux RDP client ⇢ Windows RDP server

If on the other hand you're attempting to RDP into a Windows system using a Linux RDP client then the only one I'm familiar with that has the ability to go through a TS (Terminal Server) Gateway is [xfreerdp](http://www.freerdp.com/), the [feature is specifically mentioned here and was only added recently in Nov. 2013](https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP/issues/1589).

```
$ xfreerdp /v:CLUSTER /d:DOMAIN /u:USER /p:PASSWD \
       /g:GATEWAY/gd:DOMAIN /gu:USER /gp:PASSWD
```

This is a newly added feature that is currently being worked on so I'd doubt that it would be available in your distro's repositories as of yet. So you'll have to download the latest from the project's Github repository and build it from source.

Comment: Is that the only option?  Looks complex.  How about Remmina?  Would that allow me to connect via a gateway?

Comment: @oshirowanen - I've been looking for solutions to this problem for several years, that was the only one that gave RDP access to a Linux system that I found. It is complicated but it does work, and is pretty performant.

Comment: @oshirowanen - Remmina is just a RDP/VNC client, not a server, so you need something on the server that will reply to RDP connections, hence XRDP.

Comment: @oshirowanen - If you're using Debian/Ubuntu this script might make thing go easier, http://scarygliders.net/tag/x11rdp/

Comment: Sorry about this next noob question.  Why would I need to setup a server?  the gateway.company.com and the farm.company.com are already setup and running.  Don't I just need client software to connect to the gateway inorder to connect to the rdp server?

Comment: @oshirowanen - there is no XRDP service running on Linux natively. XRDP provides this. This has nothing to do with a gateway.

Comment: Please see update 1 above.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  I have version 1.0.1 of xfreerdp installed.  Which version number includes the terminal service gateway functionality?

Comment: There isn't an actual version b/c it's coming out of the Git repository. https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP/tree/master. Whatever is in trunk/master at this time has this feature. I have 1.0.2 and it doesn't have it.